# jQuery - Variable Increment +1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've had a look round and I'm a little confused.

There seems to be several responses to my particular problem but I don't fully understand.

So if anybody could help that'd be great!

Basically, **I set a variable**

```
var firstThumb = "02"
```

And **I want to increase it**

```
function thumbIncrease() {
            firstThumb++
        };
```

on an interval

```
setInterval(function(){
            getThumb.trigger("click");
            thumbIncrease();
        }, 5000);
```

Basically what I expect to happen is - 
Every 5 seconds a click is triggered, and I want my firstThumb variable to increase by 1.

So 02, click, 03, click, 04, click....

So each time it clicks a different element.

Any help would be great!

Thanks!!

**EDIT**

Thanks for the responses! I kind of understand now! So the reason I've got a 0, is more for me than for the code. I currently have 15 things that I need clicking. 01 and 15 being 2 characters, meaning my code looks neater. Should I just man up and remove the 0? Or is there a better way of doing it?

[image: I just like the way it lines up!!]

Comment: Hint #1: `"02"` is a string, not a number

Comment: Well, that's a string.  You'd have to increase the number and conditionally concatenate it with a leading `'0'` if you want exactly that.

Comment: the reason it doens't work is because your variable is a string you then trying to convert it to a number and then add a 0 to the front of it

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov There is no string concatenation going on here. Just type coercion.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  I kind of understand now!  So the reason I've got a 0, is more for me than for the code.  I currently have 15 things that I need clicking. 01 and 15 being 2 characters, meaning my code looks neater.  Should I just man up and remove the 0?  Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Handling numbers is different to representing numbers, `1` is a number. `"1"` is a string. `01` is a number but will return as `1`. For you to prefix with Zero you can use a second variable for your visual representation of the number and make it a string.

Comment: Thanks Chris!  That's helped a lot!

Comment: @Nick Why do you want to automatically click banners in sequence? That sounds edgy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var counter = 1;

setInterval(function() {

  var _text = counter + "<br>";

  $("div").append(_text);

  counter++;   
   
},5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```

If you want it to replace the old number use `.html()` instead of `.append()`

`"01"` is a string, `1` is a number you can increment.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need zero padding:

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}

var thumbNumber = "02";

thumbNumber = parseInt(thumbNumber);
var nextNumber = pad(++thumbNumber,2);

console.log(nextNumber);
```

Live Demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/v02vgw6w/2/

Comment: Just to point this out, these days there is `String.prototype.repeat`, though it might need shimming.